# Why is this Promise not working correctly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise

I am new to jQuery Promises but I am using them fine in other parts of the app, but this one does not seem to be working as expected. Seems it is not waiting for the return before executing the next code.

```
function setActivityOnGrid(){
...snip...
var sameActivityCnt = $(actId).length;
  if(sameActivityCnt){
    sameActivityDialog().then(function(retVal) {
      if(retVal == true){
        activityid += "-"+sameActivityCnt++;
      }
    });
}
//code here is being executed before the dialog is even shown
}

function sameActivityDialog(){
  var deferred = $.Deferred();

  bootbox.confirm("You have already added this activity. Would you like to add it again?", function(result) {
    deferred.resolve(result);
  });
  return deferred.promise();
}
```

Comment: The only part of the code that waits for the dialog is the callback in `.then()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the `//code here is being executed before the dialog is even shown` to here:

```
var sameActivityCnt = $(actId).length;
if(sameActivityCnt){
  sameActivityDialog().then(function(retVal) {
    if (retVal === true){
      activityid += "-"+sameActivityCnt++;
    }

    // code goes here!!!!

  });
}
```

Inside the then callback function (or later chained then functions).

### Alternatives

```
var sameActivityCnt = $(actId).length;
sameActivityDialog().then(function(retVal) {
  if(sameActivityCnt && retVal === true){
    activityid += "-"+sameActivityCnt++;
  }

  // code goes here!!!!

});
```

or

```
var promise = sameActivityDialog();
var sameActivityCnt = $(actId).length;

if(sameActivityCnt){
  promise = promise.then(function(retVal) {
    if (retVal === true){
      activityid += "-"+sameActivityCnt++;
    }
    return retVal;
  });
}

promise = promise.then(function(retVal) {
  // code goes here!!!!
  return retVal;
});
```

And if you split this logic into smaller functions then you can actually compose this well:

```
function doIf(condition, fn) {
  return function(data) {
    if (condition) {
      return fn(data);
    } else {
      return data
    }
  };
}

function appendID(retVal) {
  if (retVal === true){
    activityid += "-"+sameActivityCnt++;
  }
  return retVal;
}

function doMoreStuff(retVal) {
  // code goes here!!!!
  return retVal;
}

var sameActivityCnt = $(actId).length;

sameActivityDialog()
  .then(doIf(sameActivityCnt, appendID))
  .then(doMoreStuff);
```

Comment: Can't move it there cause if sameActivityCnt = 0, it won't run the moved code.

Comment: Appreciate the effort. I will work something out with these. Obviously I need to learn more about how Promises work.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum, Because this was more a spattering of code snip-its then an actual answer and I felt that by letting it be a community wiki it could be updated by all and expanded upon by others who might have better pose then I.

Answer (score 1):

The promise is working correctly. A promise doesn't make a non-blocking function block.

It gives you an object which you can repeatedly add new callbacks to which will run when the non-blocking function is done.